# Is Atomic Integer incrementAndGet() thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, atomicinteger

Is Atomic Integer incrementAndGet() method thread safe? I don't see any use of synchronized keyword in it. I am using following code to generate the unique id:

```
public enum UniqueIdGenerator {
    INSTANCE;

    private AtomicLong instance = new AtomicLong(System.currentTimeMillis());

    public long incrementAndGet() {
        return instance.incrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

I am wondering if multiple threads that would call the method to generate unique ID result in any issue.

```
UniqueIdGenerator.INSTANCE.incrementAndGet()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is. And `AtomicLong` is too.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html. This is linked from the first sentence of AtomicInteger's javadoc. And it says: *A small toolkit of classes that support lock-free thread-safe programming on single variables*

Comment: Not only is it thread-safe, but in fact its thread-safety is the only reason to use it (as opposed to a plain `int`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is. It uses other, than synchronized, more efficient thread safety mechanism based on internal JDK class named `Unsafe`

Answer (score 5):

Not only `AtomicInteger` and `AtomicLong`, [atomic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) package classes are thread safe.

```
java.util.concurrent.atomic
```

> A small toolkit of classes that support lock-free thread-safe programming on single variables.

*In essence, the classes in this package extend the notion of volatile values, fields, and array elements to those that also provide an atomic conditional update operation of the form*:

```
boolean compareAndSet(expectedValue, updateValue);
```

Instances of classes `AtomicBoolean`, `AtomicInteger`, `AtomicLong`, and `AtomicReference` each provide access and updates to a single variable of the corresponding type. Each class also provides appropriate utility methods for that type. For example, classes `AtomicLong` and `AtomicInteger` provide atomic increment methods.

Answer (score 1):

YES! Its part of java.util.concurrent package.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In fact, this is [one of the stated goals of implementing `AtomicLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html#incrementAndGet()):

> An `AtomicLong` is used in applications such as atomically incremented sequence numbers

Each of the multiple threads accessing `incrementAndGet` concurrently will get a unique number.